# How to print the text right aligned in a Bluetooth POS Printer?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, byte, pos

I have been trying to do a POS app in android where I am printing the receipt on a Bluetooth printer connected to the app. I am able to print 'large', 'small' and QR code with the HOINSDK provided with the device and also I am able to align then 'left' and 'centre' but unable to align it to the 'right'. Any help is appreciated.

Below are the codes for respective things:

```
//For Large Text

                cmd[0] = 27;
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                mService.write(cmd);
                mService.sendMessage("" + large_txt.getText().toString(), "GBK");

//For Small Text
                cmd[0] = 0x1b;
                cmd[1] = 0x21;
                cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                mService.write(cmd);          
                mService.sendMessage("" + small_txt.getText().toString(), "GBK");

//For Center Alignment small text
                cmd[0] = 27;
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] |= 1;
                mService.write(cmd);
                cmd[0] = 27;
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] = 1;
                mService.write(cmd);  
                mService.sendMessage("" + center_txt.getText().toString(), "GBK");

//For centre alignment Large Text
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] |= 1;
                mService.write(cmd);
                cmd[0] = 0x1b;
                cmd[1] = 0x21;
                cmd[2] = 0x10;
                mService.write(cmd);  
                mService.sendMessage("" + center_txt.getText().toString(), "GBK");

//For Left alignment
                cmd[0] = 27;
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] |= 1;
                mService.write(cmd);
                cmd[0] = 27;
                cmd[1] = 97;
                cmd[2] = 0;
                mService.write(cmd);
                mService.sendMessage("" + left_txt.getText().toString(), "GBK");
```

If anybody can help me with the right alignment code, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue before but I did not found any solution so,  I am using below method as a solution,

Example,

```
String largetext = "Title";
String largeFontMessage = getWhiteSpace(24 - largetext.length()) + largetext;
String smalltext = "Message";
String smallFontMessage = getWhiteSpace(42 - smalltext.length()) + smalltext;

// print largeFontMessage;
// print smallFontMessage;

public static String getWhiteSpace(int size) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        builder.append(' ');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

In my case in single line **small text contains 42 characters** and **large text contains 24 characters**.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems this will be the solution in my case, these printer manufactures don't care to document formatting of receipts

Comment: Right, they don't provide such solutions in their SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Add this printer command

```
public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x02 };
```